# Insert data into file based on file name using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script that goes into a files, and for every instance of **E:**, it will replace it with **CBM-FS01|2013-02-03|E:**

```
$filenames = @("C:\SCRIPT\CBM-FS01-E-20130203114114.txt.out")
foreach ($file in $filenames) {
    $outfile = "$file" + ".sql"

    Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
       $_ -replace "E:","CBM-FS01|2013-02-03|E:" `
    } | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

If you look close, you can see that I'm getting this information based on the file name.  The file name will always be **MNEMONIC-MACHINE-DRIVE-YYYMMDDHHMMSS.txt**.

Modifying the script for a few files is fine, but I could potentially need to run this on a hundred files!  Is there a way using powershell to use the GET-CHILDITEM cmdlet and have powershell automatically perform the -replace based on the different file names?

**EDIT:**
I need to extract parts of the file name, and insert it into the file.  For example, for a file **CBM-FS01-E-20130203114114.txt**, I need to extract the mnemonic-machine (CBM-FS01) and the YYYMMDD (2013-02-03) into the file.  Hence

```
$_ -replace "E:","CBM-FS01|2013-02-03|E:" `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, provided those file name patterns are predictable (and I've predicted them correctly)

```
$filenames = @("C:\SCRIPT\CBM-FS01-E-20130203114114.txt.out")

$regex = '^([^-]+-[^-]+)-([A-Z])-(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d).+'

foreach ($file in $filenames) {

    $outfile = "$file" + ".sql"

    $ReplaceString = ($file | Split-Path -leaf) -replace $regex,'$1|$3-$4-$5|$2:'

    Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
       $_ -replace "E:",$ReplaceString
    } | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

Comment: That works!  BUT, we have a few oddballs were the file name is CBM-EXXFS-001-E-20130203114114.txt and CBMFS01-E-20130203114114.txt.  How would I modify the regex?

Comment: Disregard.  I did a little experimenting.  For the first example, I modified it to $regex = '^([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)-([A-Z])-(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d).+'

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure of the question. It sounds like you have a whole pile of files with the same pattern. You can use the -match operator to do some [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) comparison.

```
$pattern = '[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-E-[0-9]+\.txt'
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse | ? {$_.name -match $pattern}
foreach($file in $files){
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, not really want I'm trying to accomplish.  I'll edit the question to be more clear.